# Ubuntu factor for android

Tags: android

time already come to change my cellphone, so I want to buy one that is fully compatible with Ubuntu for android, so I saw a lot of videos about  milestone, Droid razr, and others that support Ubuntu for android.

My question is which cellphones support Ubuntu and which one is more stable?

for example I saw this implementation:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyeFcldavTk&feature=related

And also,there are native ones on development like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd43m08d-ro

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm much mistaken, your best bet is to wait a short while to see which manufacturer brings out a phone with Ubuntu pre-installed.

I would love to think that Canonical will distribute a version I could put on my rooted SGS3 but, unless take-up is poor by manufacturers, I don't see it happening given the vibes comming from their publicity. A massive shame but there we go. I feel we'd take it up far faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Ubuntu on Samsungs Tab
Links for how to install :

- [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/ubuntu-running-on-the-samsung-galaxy-tab)
- [Galaxy Tab Hacks](http://galaxytabhacks.com/galaxy-tab-10-1-hacks/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-galaxy-tab-10-1-tabuntu/)